# How can i implement public EventBus with NestJS?

Tags: cqrs, nestjs, event-sourcing

NestJS has a powerful CRQS module, and everything works very well, but **just in local scope**.

I want to implement an application which can listen to everything in global scope, keeping all modules 'Lazy loaded'.

I'm facing components who playing well but alone, so I can't see advantages in privately scoped events, commands and queries.

Let's imagine something like this, keeping lazy load modules:

An Orders Component receives an order, manages it's rules, commands, queries, events, stores it's relevant data and **Publish -- OrderPlacedEvent**

Other components, like Mail Component, is listening and will process it's commands, events... so
may also publish another event.

I can't see ways to achieve this implementation without loading Commands, events handlers from other components.

My question is, is there any way to implement this in NestJS public EventBus, CommandBus... and subscribe to them globally?